# RESOLVE : react error : Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs

I have this error : Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

but I don't understand how to solve it! I'm just posting my code and sorry ...

my code :

```
{this.state.messages.map(message =>
                        <li>
                            <p id="author">{message.message.author}</p>
                            <p id="date">{message.message.date}</p><br/>
                            <p id="message-content">{message.message.content}</p>
                            <button class="delete-button" type="submit" onClick={() => this.delete(message._id)}>suprimmer</button>
                            {this.state.setModify & this.state.idModify === message._id ?
                                <div id="modify-menu">
                                    {this.setState({modify: message.message.content})}
                                    <input class="modify-input" id={message._id} type="text" name="modify" value={this.state.modify} onChange={this.handleChangeModify.bind(this)}/>
                                    <button class="modify-send" id={message._id} type="submit" onClick={() => this.modify(message._id)}>envoyer</button>
                                    <button class="modify-cancel" id={message._id} type="submit" onClick={() => this.setState({setModify: false})}>annuler</button>
                                </div>:
                                <button class="modify-button" id={message._id} type="submit" onClick={this.activeModify.bind(this)}>modifier</button>
                            }
                            <hr></hr>
                        </li>
                    )}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using `{this.setState({modify: message.message.content})}` inside your render. For each element of the array `this.state.messages` it re-renders the modify object inside the state.

You should move the `{this.setState({modify: message.message.content})}` call to an `onClick` or an `onChange` function. Since you modify the state on each render, it gets into an infinite loop, and hence, `Maximum update depth exceeded`

Instead of setting the `modify` field while rendering, you can directly do that in `componentDidMount`:

```
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/messages`)
            .then(res => {
                const messages = res.data;
                this.setState({
                    messages: messages,
                    message: '',
                    modify: messages.map(message => message.message.content),
                });
            })
    }
```

Comment: ok I thought about it but I need of this.state.message.map() and if i'm not in this i can't to do what I want

Comment: I will try to help you, can you create a `codesandbox` environment? What are you trying to achieve with ` {this.setState({modify: message.message.content})}` inside the render?

Comment: Nice, now why do you want to setState while rendering?

Comment: because I want when a click on the button "modifer" i have an input with the message but the message must be the right one so i use the id for searche the good message

Comment: you can show the error when you click on button "modifier"

Comment: See updated answer. It is the best of my effort to wrap my head around the problem, hope it helps!

Comment: You removed the `setState` call inside the render right? Does it still give the same error?

Comment: no I don't have the error but i can't modify the input and the message into the input it's not the good message

Answer (score 0):

ok i resolve my problem with this code :

```
activeModify(event){
    event.persist();
    this.setState({
        setModify: true,
        idModify: event.target.id
    })
    this.state.messages.map(message => {
        if (message._id === event.target.id) {
            this.setState({
                modify: message.message.content
            });
        }
    });
}
```